# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'alljoyn/BusAttachment.h' file not found

Tags: xcode5

when I enter the following:

"$(SRCROOT)/../alljoynsdk/alljoyn_core/build/darwin/arm/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/$(CONFIGURATION)/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn"

to the Header Search Paths field and build it .it still says that Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'alljoyn/BusAttachment.h' file not found.

I checked the alljoyn path file and the BusAttachment.h file exist in that file.

SOS
Best regards,
Liam

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is :
1) Add "libstdc++.6.dylib" Framework and 
2) Add one more path in "Library Search Paths"
"$(OPENSSL_ROOT)/build/$(CONFIGURATION)-$(PLATFORM_NAME)"